# Suggestions on Point Cloud fusion

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to fuse point clouds into one. These Point clouds are acquired from multiple cameras. Below is the detailed information about setup-

Three Kinect v2 sensors are mounted on tripods in such a way that they are making 120 degree angle from each other in a horizontal plane. Hence one can assume that these Kinect sensors are kept in the circumference of a sphere and pointing towards the center of the sphere. All three Kinect sensors are tilted vertically downwards approximately 30 degrees. The object which is being scanned is kept inside the sphere and visible from all Kinect sensors.

I am able to acquire three point clouds simultaneously from these sensors. Now I want to fuse three clouds to make 1 compete cloud.

What algorithm would I use for this?

Comment: Tool/software requests are off-topic here.

Comment: @D.W. : Can you please tell me where should I ask this question?

Comment: I don't know of any place where it is likely to be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use a method for point cloud registration, also known as point set registration or point cloud alignment.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_registration.  [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus)-like methods may also be useful.

Comment: From wiki, *point set registration, also known as point matching, is the process of finding a spatial transformation that aligns two point sets.* I am not sure if I am looking for this. Since the point cloud acquired from multiple cameras are not taken from the same view. The point clouds acquired from the three Kinect cameras are different. For example, the first Kinect camera can see only front and top. The second camera can see back, left and top. Similarly third camera can see right side and top. Please note that these positions are roughly mentioned by me and not known in advance.

Comment: @RaviJoshi, you could try using point set registration on the set of points that are (likely to be) visible from both cameras.